# ZipEntry.getTime() unpredictable results

Tags: java, android, timezone

I am experimenting with ZipEntry.getTime() on Android. However I am seeing different results on different devices for the SAME zip&file:
1419755996000,
1419752396000,
1419730796000,
1419770396000,
1419737996000,
1419745196000,
1419759596000,
...

Differences from my device in hours are as follows:
+2h,
+1h,
-5h,
+6h,
-3h,
-1h,
...

These numbers are obtained from real devices around the world by means of analytics&logging.
Since I am using the long result of getTime() directly I am not expecting for the timezone to matter.

How can these differences by explained and what can I do to obtain a uniform result on all devices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a zip file, the date and time of each entry are stored as a year, month, day, hour, minute and second, coded up into a `long` value.  No timezone is specified.  When this is converted to a Java `Date` (which represents an instant in time) in the course of the `getTime()` method, it is converted according to the system timezone.

Comment: can I somehow normalize the result to UTC timezone so all will be the same ?

Comment: You'll probably want to use something like `TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(???)` to figure out how much to adjust it by, but you'll run into trouble close to the times when daylight savings starts and ends.